# Why is Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged inconsistently slow?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I wrote the following code for debugging puposes:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function is run each time the page is loaded.
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {


        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Use this to check whether the API is supported in the Word client.
            if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
                // Do something that is only available via the new APIs

                Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, onSelectionChanged);
            }
            else {
                // Just letting you know that this code will not work with your version of Word.
                $('#status').html('This code requires WordApi 1.1 or greater.');
            }
        });
    };

    var c = 1;
    function onSelectionChanged(eventArgs) {
        c++;
        $('#status').html('onSelectionChanged() call '+c+);
    }
})();
```

This code only sometimes reacts to changes. Sometimes reeaaly slow. Sometimes (I guess, if it is too slow and there have been multiple changes in between, it does not recognize them und prints `onSelectionChanged() call 4` after a while, even though, there have been many more changes.
Other times, if I close Word, and open it again, it just works as a charm. Then I close it and open it again, and again, it fails - It is completely inconsistant. Thereby this feature is effectively not usable.

I tested this on different machines, different versions of Windows and it occures independend of the utilization of the system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to repro your issue. The event works quite consistently.

Its not related but is there a specific reason why you are checking the 1.1 requirement set? This event was shipped on the first release of the API so that's not needed.

If you can provide your build number and a sample document and video of whats going on we could investigate in more detail.

thanks!

Comment: I am afraid, I am not allowed to share this document. I tried to reproduce the issue with many other documents and failed. However, my whole Add-In is built around this document.
The document has > 200 pages and contains mainly tables with text.

Comment: In what build you are?

Comment: I had this Issue with 16.0.4549.1000 as well as with Word Version 1706 (Build 8229.2086). Now I built a workaround, avoiding the event.

Comment: I am running into more and more trouble / what seems to be many different bugs, which are only occurring in this document.

Would it be possible to sign a non disclosure agreement with microsoft, share this document with you and work on a bug fix?

Comment: Follow up: Michael i sent you an email with more questions but I got a "The email address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the recipient's email address and try to resend the message. If the problem continues, please contact your email admin."